# How to get YouTube API muted in Internet Explorer 11 and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, youtube, safari

I have tried to mute YouTube API as you might see, but it works in Chrome and Firefox. How can I get this muted in Internet Explorer and Safari as well. Is there a way to fix this with JavaScript? Have Googling around, but could not find any proper answer to solve this.

```js
var player;
var player2;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){
 player = new YT.Player("video1", {
  videoId: "KKp9g8fTBDQ",
  width: 300,
  height: 200, 
  playerVars: {
   "autoplay": 1,  
   "controls": 1,
   "showinfo": 0,
   "modestbranding": 0,
   "loop": 1,
   "fs": 0,
   "cc_load_policy": 0,
   "iv_load_policy": 3,
            "mute": 1  
   },
  events: {
      "onReady": onPlayerReady
  }
 });
 player2 = new YT.Player("video2", {
  videoId: "O5-o0DpB6z0",
  width: 300,
  height: 200, 
  playerVars: {
   "autoplay": 1,
   "controls": 1,
   "showinfo": 0,
   "modestbranding": 0,
   "loop": 1,
   "fs": 0,
   "cc_load_policy": 0,
   "iv_load_policy": 3, 
            "mute": 1  
  },
  events: {
      "onReady": onPlayerReady
  }
 });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.setPlaybackQuality("hd1080");
    event.target.setVolume(50);
    player.mute();
}

//tried these options as well, but nothing works. 

var video1 = document.getElementById("video1");
var video2 = document.getElementById("video2");

video1.mute();
video2.mute();

video1.volume = 0.0;
video2.volume = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `player.mute();` inside the `onPlayerReady` function you should use `event.target.mute()`. This way you call the `mute` function that is related to the specific video that the `onPlayerReady` callback was called for.

Here is a working codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kXOXWo

(It will not work inside the codepen with IE due to cross origin and iframe, but the code was checked with both Chrome, Firefox, IE and Safari and all work).

## update

For some reason when using `"autoplay": 1` together with the `mute()` option - every several times you do a refresh in `ie` your video is still not mute. The solution I found for this was to set `"autoplay": 0` together with

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.mute();
    event.target.playVideo();
}
```

This is the complete codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NAQXar

Hope now it will work :)

Comment: If I set the volume of a video to for example 50%, the sound will not be muted when IE browser is refreshed.

Comment: Can you explain? What do you mean by "if I set the volume of the video to 50%"? Where? Where? How?

Comment: If I open the website in IE 11 browser, set the volume of the video manually to 50% for instance. Refresh the IE browser, the sound will not be muted unfortunately.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem you mentioned but it's not consistent. It happen only part of the time that I do a refresh. I will update the answer with a better solution.

Comment: Not working, the video's do not show up anymore when I add the variables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122031/discussion-between-dekel-and-front-end-developer).

Comment: Not sure which variables you are talking about.

Comment: It appears that the solution to the mute problem causes the videos to pause in IE11 on refresh. (Which is fine by me; just saying.)